# TypeScript: array.map force return type?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a function that can take either a number or an array of numbers as it's input.
This function returns a string if a number is inputted, or an array of strings if an array of numbers is inputted.

**Here's my problem**
I use `array.map` to get the resulting array. `array.map`'s implicit return type is any. This means that TypeScript expects my function's return type to be `any`, or it'll throw me this error:
[image]
*ignore the `typeof` in my arrow function in this screenshot, leftover code*

Notice I'm using a bit of recursion here.
I know that the `array.map` function will only return an array of strings, so I don't want my function's return type to be `any`. I want my functions return type to be `string | string[]`. However, since TypeScript thinks the array.map might return something else, it yells at me.

Is there a way to force the `array.map` function to return an array of strings? Or to make TS understand what I'm trying to do here?

// Function that swaps a note value with it's numerical value for calculations
function numToLet(input: number | number[], isSharp: boolean)  {

```
//  Determine which reference key to use based on if we're viewing flats or sharps (isSharp)
let reference = [];
if (isSharp) {
    reference = ['G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G'];
} else {
    reference = ['Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B', 'C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G'];
}


if (typeof input === 'number') {
    return reference[input];
}

if (typeof input === 'object') {
    return input.map(item => numToLet(item, isSharp));
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `.map` itself, really, but the recursion. As the error message says, you should add a return type so TypeScript can understand what the return type can be, given the recursion.

To make TS understand that all code paths return a value, return unconditionally if the input isn't a number.

```
function numToLet(input: number | number[], isSharp: boolean): string | Array<string> {
    const reference = isSharp
        ? ['G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G'];
        : ['Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B', 'C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G'];
    if (typeof input === 'number') {
        return reference[input];
    }
    return input.map(item => typeof numToLet(item, isSharp));
}
```

But this might not be entirely desirable because it results in

```
const result = numToLet(3, true);
```

being typed as a string, not a number - you might want a more precise type, which could be accomplished by declaring beforehand:

```
function numToLet(input: number, isSharp: boolean): string;
function numToLet(input: number[], isSharp: boolean): string[];
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of overload signatures! That worked perfectly, thanks. Do overload signatures get removed on compile, since it seems that their only purpose is for TypeScript syntax?

Comment: Exactly, they're only for TypeScript, and do not exist in emitted code